# Pass function (delegate?) to function expecting object as parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm writing a class that implements 3rd party interface.  One of the functions of the interface accepts a parameter of type "object".

Within the function, I need to call a function that I want to pass in to the function as the object parameter, but I can't get it to work.

Example:

```
public class ABC : Ixyz
{
   ...
   public void DoSomething(object parameter);
   {
      // Here I will execute the function passed in
   }
   ...
}

public void MySomething()
{
   ...
}

public void SomeFunction()
{
   ABC myABCobject = new ABC();

   myABCobject.DoSomething(MySomething);
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

Cannot convert method group 'MySomething' to non-delegate type
'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

I have the feeling that I should be doing something with delegates, but since I'm implementing a 3rd party interface, I can't change the signature of the function.

Can I somehow pass in a reference to this function that's expecting an "object"?  I would think that I could, since Delegate inherits from Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try casting your parameter to the call to DoSomething as an action - e.g.

```
myABCobject.DoSomething((Action)MySomething);
```

I'm pretty sure that'll work...

in fact I just tested it and it does - you can cast the action back in the DoSomething method and invoke it - e.g.

```
var newparameter = (Action) parameter;
 newparameter();
```